# Eigen SparseLU solve error read access violation, this->m_sup_to_col was 0x111011101110112

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, access-violation, solver

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 and I'm trying to use the Eigen library in c++ to solve large sparse linear systems. I have everything wrapped in my class Domain2D with defined stiffness matrix and load vector with load vector being my own long double type:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<long double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> VectorXld; // somewhere way up in the code

class Domain2D {
private:
    ...
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<long double, Eigen::ColMajor> constant_stiffness;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<long double, Eigen::ColMajor> convection_stiffness;
    ...
    VectorXld load;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void load_constant_stiffness() {
        ...
        resize, reserve, fill up with elements
    }
    ...
    void load_convection_stiffness() {
        ...
    }
    void load_RHS() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, somewhere in the class I have the following routine:

```
void advance_step(const int &step) {
        ...
        Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<long double, Eigen::ColMajor>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> solver;
        Eigen::SparseMatrix<long double, Eigen::ColMajor> M;
        VectorXld res, res_new;
        res.resize(2 * N + n);
        ...
        while (d > 1e-5) {
            d = 0;
            load_convection_stiffness();
            load_RHS();
            M = constant_stiffness + convection_stiffness;
            M.makeCompressed();
            solver.analyzePattern(M);
            solver.factorize(M);
            res_new = solver.solve(load);
            ...
        }
        Save("output\\results\\", step);
        t += dt;
    }
```

The program fails on the last mentioned line: `res_new = solver.solve(M);`

It shows me a file called "SparseLU_SupermodalMatrix.h", the routine it fails in is `void MappedSuperNodalMatrix<Scalar,Index_>::solveInPlace( MatrixBase<Dest>&X) const` and the line is `Index fsupc = supToCol()[k];` and the error it shows is

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.

this->m_sup_to_col was 0x111011101110112.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I was searching a bit and I found that if I use eigen objects in my class, I should add line `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;` in the public section, which I did, to no avail. All matrices are of a proper size, as well as the vector of long doubles. I have been solving these systems for some time and it worked, but suddenly, this happens. What could be the cause?

P.S.: I loaded the matrix and load vector to mathematica and even with the standard precision, I get a solution which looks absolutely fine, so it's not like the system is ill-conditioned.

Answer (score 3):

Some tips:

1. You need to check that the factorization went well by checking that `solver.info()==Eigen::Success` after the call to `factorize()`.
2. Try with the head of the 3.3 branch [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.zip) to see whether this issue has already been resolved.
3. Make sure you tried without `NDEBUG` defined (aka. debug mode in visual) to see whether Eigen triggers some insightful assertions.
4. Checking with `double` instead of `long double` might help to isolate the issue. To this end, you can cast locally `M` and `load` with `.cast<double>()`.
5. Running your program within a memory debugger might help too.
6. After trying all of these, share your matrix `M` with Eigen's team to let them (i.e., myself ;) ) reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips on debugging Eigen routines. I finally found out what the problem is. Incorporating boundary conditions, I sometimes, instead of calculating the whole row of the matrix, just set M(i, i) equal to 1 and set the RHS b(i) to the BC. However, I forgot to do this for one instance, effectively leaving the equation 0 = nonzero in the system of eqns. It's a mystery how Mathematica failed to recognize this. It is nice that Eigen didn't provide me with some bogus "solution", however access violation error is not very clear in this case.

Comment: Would it be possible for Eigen to tell us users that the system of equations is not self-compatible, instead of crashing? Perhaps some tool that'd tell us that which rows are linearly dependent and have different RHS's, so the system is not consisent?